# Is there a way to manipulate inputs in Laravel Model before storing them?

Tags: php, laravel, model

In Laravel, I have used a model's create method in many controllers,

Now I need to perform `strip_tags($comment)` to a specific input in all those controllers before it is inserted in database with `create()` method like this:

```
Comment:create([
    'comment' => $comment,
    ...
]);
```

Should I repeatedly do this in all controllers:

```
$comment = strip_tags($comment); // < Is it possible to do this on model's file so we don't repeat it every time? 

Comment:create([
    'comment' => $comment,
    ...
]);
```

Or this is something that can be achieved in the Model?

Comment: Are you stripping tags to prevent XSS?

Comment: @Hardood Yes, because I have to use `{!! ... !!}` when displaying this content (so no escaping there), and I also want to allow some HTML tags, while striping others.

Comment: You can use Laravel Observer to do that. Or using event Closures in your model

Answer (score 2):

You may use `model events` to make checks and arrangements before saving it.

add following method to your model class;

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::saving(function ($model) {
        $model->comment = strip_tags($model->comment);
        // do your pre-checks or operations.
    });
}
```

here is a [useful post](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started) to read about it

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it directly in the model, it's called [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator). If your column name is **comment** then the mutator function will be called **setCommentAttribute**.

```
public function setCommentAttribute($comment)
{
    $this->attributes['comment'] = strip_tags($comment);
}
```

Any place where save/update is used for this model, the *comment* data will go through the *set...* function.